# Object has no attribute in python

Tags: python, class, jupyter-notebook

I am writing a code in pythony, where I want my ball to move on a graph, and save the positions in a list (posx and posy) I made a ball class, but when I call the constructor, I get this error message:
'Ball' object has no attribute 'posx'. This is my code:

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self,xvelocity=1, yvelocity=1, inx=1,iny=5, posx=[],posy=[]):
        self.xvelocity=xvelocity
        self.yvelocity=yvelocity
        #giving velocity
        self.inx=inx
        self.iny=iny
        #defining starting position
        self.posx[0]=self.inx
        self.posy[0]=self.iny

        


ball=Ball()
```

Do you know why this happens? Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you try `self.posx[0]=self.inx` `self.posx` is not defined. Same for `self.posy`. Finally - look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/4046632 to prevent the biggest issue in your code - mutable default arguments

Comment: If you want to pass  `posx` and `posy` as arguments and assuming you fix the error, do you really want to overwrite the element with index 0? Maybe you don't need `posx` and `posy` as parameters in your `__init__` method?

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants to add the element to the beginning of the list but not overwrite what is already at `[0]`? If so they can use insert: `posx.insert(0, inx)`, then just set `self.posx = posx`. Or even cleaner: `self.posx = [inx] + posx`. [example](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/SteelblueVillainousProgrammers#main.py)

Comment: I want to add inx and iny as the first element in my list, and later on in the code, expand the posx and posy list. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the attributes posx and posy as lists first. The next question would be if you actually want the position lists passed as argument.

```
    self.posx = [self.inx]
    self.posy = [self.iny]
```

Comment: Note that OP wants to pass posx and posy as arguments.

Comment: That's possible, although not clear as you pointed out. Let's see if OP clarifies their intentions.

Comment: The OP appears to be confused as to how the arguments differ from class attributes; `posx` and `posy` almost certainly are *not* needed as arguments.